# Warn in VS Code when Promise return type is unawaited?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code typescript and am wondering if there is a way for the editor to display some kind of warning whenever there is an async function call (function returns a `Promise`) but the caller does not await it (so that the programmer does not accidentally assume that a function is synchronous and use it as such).

Comment: I don't know about VSCode, but IntelliJ *et al.* have that. If you're looking for plugin recommendations that's off topic, though.

Comment: Not natively, but with [vscode-eslint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint) you could configure the rule [no-floating-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) which does exactly what you want.

Comment: @GOTO0 's comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using typescript, the type system should alert you that you can't use a promise wherever you use the resolved value of that promise:

```
function foo(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(123))
}

const myNumber: number = foo() // forgot await
// ^ Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=31#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAXIgCgJzgFsYBnAUwB4wQiAjc-APkQG8BYAKER8X3Kgh8SMOQDueQiQpp+pOABsAbuUQBeFnMUq0ARgBMAZgwYuAXy5cICUlEREAngDlaDfDhr1G65KkxA)

So, in effect, typescript already does what you want, just not in the way you're thinking.

---

Also, there are very good reasons that a promise may not be awaited. One maybe that you want a bunch of async operations in parallel, so you collect the promises and pass them `Promise.all`. Or perhaps you're at the top level which does not allow `await`, and it's simpler to use `then` instead.

So instead, just let the type system work as intended and don't worry about it. Doing it wrong *will* give you type errors like the one above when you start to actual use the awaited values.

Comment: There are bunch of reason and I guess many people like me would like to be explicit about it. I wish I could annotate something like // ts-ignore-await . I always hit this case when I get Promise<Val> instead of Val because I forgot to await. I think the implicit nature causes many bugs etc. We can compare it with Rust where compiler at least warns?

Comment: Your answer is unnecessarily dismissive.  The type system catches this particular error, but a much more insidious error is when you don't specifically care about the return value (example: `await writeToDB(data)`), where forgetting the await is silently ignored, but is likely to result in race conditions and subtle bugs.  A compiler warning for that omission would be meaningful.  (I'll also second aftershock's recommendation of looking at Rust, which handles this very well.  Forgetting to await is a bug, but you can explicitly discard if you want/need to.)

Comment: @GrandOpener you're not entirely wrong, especially in the `Promise<void>` case where a function does side effects. I've been doing some backend testing lately and when you have calls that setup database records in a `beforeAll` but forget an `await` then it's not super obvious why the test failed. The way that you describe Rust doing it does makes a lot of sense. But in JS/TS/Ecmascript async/await is opt in rather than the default. So the best you can get is an eslint rule.